# All of Datepicker and Datecontrol is not working in activeForm Kartik

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have added datecontrol(kartik extension) in my activeForm of YII2, but it is not working.

It is shown in the activeForm, but when i click the cancel button and picker button, it has not any popup.
So I added the datecontrol and datepicker button to the out of activeForm

```
<?php 
 $form = ActiveForm::begin(
    ['type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL]); 
    echo Form::widget([

        'model' => $model,
        'form' => $form,
        'columns' => 1,
        'attributes' => [

            'first_name' => ['type' => Form::INPUT_TEXT, 'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter First Name...', 'maxlength' => 255]],

 //           ............................


            'created' => ['type' => Form::INPUT_WIDGET, 'widgetClass' => DateControl::classname(),'options' => [
                                'type' => DateControl::FORMAT_DATETIME],
                                'ajaxConversion'=>false,
                         ],
 ]

    ]);?>
```

I tested adding datepicker to out of the activeform with this code.

```
echo DateTimePicker::widget([
    'name' => 'dp_3',
    'type' => DateTimePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
    'value' => '23-Feb-1982 12:35 AM',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
        'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy HH:ii P'
    ]
]);
```

But the same, is shown but not working.
I think there was many js files(maybe 2 or more) and datepicker.js file is not working because of the another one.
But didn't know how to fix that.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cristianr909090/pymdg1tr/1/

Comment: there is an below error in my browser :jquery.js:3850 Uncaught ReferenceError: datetimepicker_410d83a3 is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (4:1047)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3557)
    at process (jquery.js:3625)

Comment: the JSFiddle will not execute your PHP  code. Please put there the generated HTML. You can find it using Page Source in your browser.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cristianr909090/zgdrbjLc/1/

Comment: I have taken a look. On the Fiddle the page is broken, parts of the CSS code is shown on the page, there are 84 client-side errors as well. If I were you I would start fixing these errors first and when the page is not broken would turn my attention to the datepicker.